# обработчик php для прикрепленных файлов к форме

Tags: php, html, form

Есть форма обратной связи, есть обработчик php для этой формы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы приходили фото из соответствующих input'ов? Не хватает головы самому додуматься, остальное сделано...Буду благодарен!

**HTML КОД**

```
<form action="forma.php" method="POST" class="profile__form form mt-50" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="flex flex--wrap flex--justify-between mb-60">
                        <div class="max-560 form__inputs">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name" class="form__label">Имя:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form__input" data-name="Имя" data-required="" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex flex--wrap">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="city" class="form__label">Город проживания:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form__input" data-name="Город проживания" data-required="" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="age" class="form__label">Возраст:</label>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="age" id="age" class="form__input" data-name="Возраст" value="18" data-required="" required>
                                    <div class="input__dropdown">
                                        <div class="drop-current"></div>
                                        <div class="drop-list">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li value="18">18</li>
                                                <li value="19">19</li>
                                                <li value="20">20</li>
                                                <li value="21">21</li>
                                                <li value="22">22</li>
                                                <li value="23">23</li>
                                                <li value="24">24</li>
                                                <li value="25">25</li>
                                                <li value="26">26</li>
                                                <li value="27">27</li>
                                                <li value="28">28</li>
                                                <li value="29">29</li>
                                                <li value="30">30</li>
                                                <li value="31">31</li>
                                                <li value="32">32</li>
                                                <li value="33">33</li>
                                                <li value="34">34</li>
                                                <li value="35">35</li>
                                                <li value="36">36</li>
                                                <li value="37">37</li>
                                                <li value="38">38</li>
                                                <li value="39">39</li>
                                                <li value="40">40</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex flex--wrap">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="phone" class="form__label">Номер телефона:</label>
                                    <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" class="form__input" placeholder="+___ (___) ___-__-__" data-name="Номер телефона" data-required="" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="insta" class="form__label">Ваш Instagram:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="insta" name="insta" class="form__input" data-name="Instagram">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="max-560 form__files">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label for="photo-full" class="form__label">Добавьте Ваше фото:</label>
                                <div class="flex flex--wrap flex--justify-between">
                                    <div class="file-space">
                                        <input type="file" id="photo-full" name="full-photo" accept="image/*" data-name="Фото в полный рост" data-required="" required>
                                        <span class="file-space__text">В полный рост</span>
                                        <span class="file-space__img file-space__img--add circle"></span>
                                        <span class="file-space__change">изменить</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="file-space">
                                        <input type="file" id="photo-portrait" name="photo-portrait" data-name="Фото портрет" accept="image/*" data-required="" required>
                                        <span class="file-space__text">Портрет \<br\> (без использования snapchat)</br\></span>
                                        <span class="file-space__img file-space__img--add circle"></span>
                                        <span class="file-space__change">изменить</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>

                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label for="" class="form__label">Имеете ли Вы опыт в бизнесе?</label>
                                <div class="flex flex--wrap flex--justify-start">
                                    <div class="rel radio-group">
                                        <input type="radio" id="exp-true" value="Да" name="experience" data-name="Опыт" checked="">
                                        <label for="exp-true" class="label__radio">
                                            Да                                            </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="rel radio-group">
                                        <input type="radio" id="exp-false" value="Нет" name="experience" data-name="Опыт">
                                        <label for="exp-false" class="label__radio">
                                            Нет                                            </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form__utm">
                        <input type="hidden" data-name="utm_source" name="utm_source" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" data-name="utm_medium" name="utm_medium" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" data-name="utm_campaign" name="utm_campaign" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" data-name="utm_term" name="utm_term" value="">
                        <input type="hidden" data-name="utm_content" name="utm_content" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" data-name="utm_term" name="utm_term" value="">      
                            
                    </div>
                    <img class="form__loading" src="dist/static/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="">
                    <div class="form__response mb-60">
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn block-center block" type="submit">Отправить анкету</button>
                </form>
```

**PHP КОД**

```
<?php
    $to = "email@email.ru";
    $tema = "Обратная связь"; // тема полученного емайла 
    $message .= "Имя: ".$_POST['name']."<br>";
    $message .= "Город проживания: ".$_POST['city']."<br>";
    $message .= "Возраст: ".$_POST['age']."<br>"; 
    $message .= "Телефон: ".$_POST['phone']."<br>";
    $message .= "instagram: ".$_POST['insta']."<br>";
    $message .= "Фото-1: ".$_POST['full-photo']."<br>"; 
    $message .= "Фото-2: ".$_POST['photo-portrait']."<br>";
    $message .= "Опыт?: ".$_POST['experience']."<br>"; 
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; // заголовок соответствует формату плюс символ перевода строки
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n"; // указывает на тип посылаемого контента
    mail($to, $tema, $message, $headers); //отправляет получателю на емайл значения переменных
    header('Location: index.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы хранятся в массиве `$_FILES`, `tmp_name` - это временно сохраненный файл, который нужно переместить в постоянное хранилище

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["full-photo"]["tmp_name"];
$name = basename($_FILES["full-photo"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
...
$message .= "Фото-1: <img src=\"". "$uploads_dir/$name" ."\"></img><br>";
```

Comment: извиняюсь, поправил код html. У меня там нет еще одной формы отдельной для фото.

Comment: я привел базовый пример как оно делается, а Вы уже подстраивайте  под свои нужды